# 80s (or earlier) sci-fi story set in a near-future disaster world; female character terrified of men after she was assaulted and had a nipple excised

Tags: story-identification

This book must be at least 40 years old as I read it in my local library when I was a boy... I can remember very little except:

I believe it was a near-future world disaster scenario. Main protagonist was male. Second protagonist was female and was terrified of men as she had been assaulted and one nipple had been excised.

Crossbows were in use.

Comment: Any other SFF details you may remember other than "near future world disaster scenario" Maybe something about what the setting was?

Comment: Do you remeber any book or movie of the same time?

Comment: Technically Lucien's A true History, or Kepler's Somnium, or the Blazing World are very old science fiction books.  Merely being over 40 years old is not enough to classy a book as being a very old science fiction books.

Comment: Could it have been a short story? Robert Sheckley's The Girls and Nugent Miller comes close, though the woman (with a party of schoolgirls in tow) doesn't so much fear men as hate them, having been driven mad by the trauma of the nuclear war. The story was written in 1960.

Comment: It could have been a short story yes. There was no party of schoolgirls. I have a sense that the woman was the crossbow user - also that their was a scene involving a bathtub when the two finally get close. As to the age of the work I don’t know what yardstick is in use, just that it was written pre 1978... I don’t know how long before.. Many apologies for vagueness.

Comment: The main character of the book, *Friday*, by Robert A. Heinlein, had a nipple removed during torture in the opening chapter of the book. But the rest of the book doesn't sound like what you described.

Comment: If an answer below is the correct one (as seems to be the case) you can accept it by clicking the checkmark below the count in the answer below.

Comment: @LincolnMan, it's absolutely not *Friday*. She doesn't become terrified of men as a result of the torture, even as rape is a part of it. If anything, she's annoyed by the people who ordered it because they should be aware torture doesn't work as a way of extracting accurate information, and even her torturers are somewhat apologetic about it because they know it as well but they're under orders.

Answer (score 13):

I believe this is *False Dawn* by Chelsea Quinn Yarbro, **published in 1978**. I own only the German version (*Falsche Dämmerung*, Heyne 1980), so digging for quotes does not make much sense.
The following synopsis is from http://www.apocalypsebooks.com/books/false-dawn/. I put in boldface details that fit the question.

> In a brutal and wasted world there was only one law—survive at any
>   cost.
>
> It is **the turn of the twenty-first century**, **War, disease, and
>   pollution** have made the Earth nearly unfit for human habitation. In
>   America, food is scarce, and what food remains is quickly confiscated
>   by the Pirates—a murderous band of raiders determined to save
>   themselves and to destroy the last stronghold of civilized human
>   beings—the mutant population.
>
> One of these mutants, a woman named Thea, has eluded the Pirates for
>   years. Armed only with a **crossbow**, her pride, and her common sense,
>   she has been slowly making her way Eastward to Gold Lake—a legendary
>   place of safety and enlightenment. Until one day she meets Evan
>   Montague, a man who needs her help, a man who is also on the run from
>   the Pirates, but for a different reason—he once led the Pirates
>   himself and has now become their most bitter and most hunted enemy.
>
> Together, Thea and Evan trek across a dangerous and wasted California,
>   hoping to survive the brutality of twenty-first-century life... and,
>   perhaps, to find Eden before they die.

But what really makes me sure it is *False Dawn* is the part about the nipple. I clearly remember a scene where Thea (the main protagonist in my memory) puts up a fight, and her opponent says something like, "Stop it, or I will tear the other one off with my teeth."

Not for the faint of heart, but an impressive work that made me a Yarbro fan.

PS I have been lurking and reading for a while, but this is my first answer. Hints for improvement are most welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SFF! That is a nicely written first answer! As to improvements, the story appears to be [available at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/falsedawn00yarb/page/n223), albeit requiring an account; you could fetch some quotes here. But once again, that's already a nice answer as is - I hope you stick around to provide more questions/answers! :)

Comment: Nice answer indeed!

Comment: Gonger I think you have it! Chelsea Quinn Yarbro definitley rings bells! Well done! I will see if I can find a copy in English or the online version. Well done!